# Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 not starting GUI after python3 reinstall

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, python3, mate

I have Lenovo Thinkpad T-480, with dual boot Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS and Windows 10 using GRUB. Normally I use Ubuntu-MATE for my programming needs and Windows 10 for editing images.

Two days ago I removed python3 from  my Ubuntu-MATE enviromnet, I needed to switch to python3.7 and python3.6 was provided by the OS. I thought I could simply remove one and point python3 to a newly installed version, but it wasn't so simple, other parts of my system depended on the python3.6 I just removed. After some time working, I managed to install both versions and using update-alternatives both pointed to python3. Everything looked normal.

However when I started my laptop yesterday I realised that something had gone wrong since GRUB didin't say I was starting Ubuntu, but rather Debian - Linux Generic.

If I chose that option it simply wouldn't start, and get stuck in the pre-login load logo. I started in Debian - Linux Generic in recovery mode and was able to get a working terminal, and start the GUI using command `startx`. But keeps not working if I try to start normally.

What I have tried:

- Point python3 back to python 3.6
- Cleaned and reloaded packages sources and reinstalled the desktop
- Reinstall `python3-apt` package.

Can you help me? Of course I can just re install Ubuntu cleanly, but I was hoping there was a nice solution. If you need any more details, please comment and I will be happy to provide more info.

EDIT: I think it can be something with LightDM, `systemctl status lightdm` shows:

lightdm.service

```
 - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; indirect; vendor preset:
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-03-14 23:44:38 -03; 11min a
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
  Process: 1592 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lightdm (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1580 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(basename $(cat /etc/X11/default-dis
 Main PID: 1592 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mar 14 23:44:38 nico-ThinkPad-T480 systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service hold-off
mar 14 23:44:38 nico-ThinkPad-T480 systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restar
mar 14 23:44:38 nico-ThinkPad-T480 systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
mar 14 23:44:38 nico-ThinkPad-T480 systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request re
mar 14 23:44:38 nico-ThinkPad-T480 systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with resu
mar 14 23:44:38 nico-ThinkPad-T480 systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager
```

I have never worked with the login manager before, so I don't even know where to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

Self-answering for documenting purposes:

As I said in my edit, I narrowed it down to the lightdm display manager and found out in the logs it was failing to load a greeter.

So I installed `slick-greeter` and then on `/etc/lightdm` created a file named `lightdm.conf` with the following content:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=slick-greeter
```

and now everything seems fine.

Still haven't worked on that GRUB issue.